# How to run program from %PATH% instead of current folder

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

If I run a program that exists in %PATH% in Windows when there is a program with the same name in the current folder it will select the one in current folder instead. Is there any way to prevent this (to disregard current folder)?

The reason for my question is that I have a Java program that I have placed in the Run-key in the registry like this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
MyProgram = javaw -cp MyProgram.jar com.mycompany.MyProgram
```

The problem is that on one computer I tested on it didn't work. It complained about the wrong JRE version (1.7 instead of 1.8). I found that on this computer someone installed JRE 1.8 over 1.7, but the 1.7 files are still left in Windows\System32.

If I launch javaw -cp MyProgram.jar com.mycompany.MyProgram manually in a command prompt it works, unless I have Windows\System32 as current folder.

The problem is that when Windows starts the programs during startup (from the Run-key in registry) it has System32 as current folder and therefore it will use the wrong JRE-version.

I can fix this on this specific computer by removing the incorrect exe-files from System32, but I want it to work when someone else installs it somewhere else, and the best way I have come to think of is to forcing Windows to use %PATH%, but I don't know how.

Comment: Provide full path to `javaw` in the Run-key in the registry. I guess the `MyProgram` is _your own_ registry entry. Consider making it `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type instead of `REG_SZ` so you could provide somethig like `%javaw%` if an alike environment variable exists (I don't know it not having java installed).

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off

set "to_run=javaw.exe"
for %%# in ("%to_run%") do set "ppath=%%~$PATH:#"
echo %ppath%
"%ppath%" -cp MyProgram.jar com.mycompany.MyProgram
```

for more info about `%~$PATH:` syntax check `for /?`

Comment: Thanks, very nice solution. I want to avoid a batch-file in my case though, so I will go with the solution from @skrabban, but very good to know about the %~$PATH: syntax for future needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this by starting in another directory where java is unlikely to exist like so:

`cmd /c (cd\ && start /b javaw -cp MyProgram.jar com.mycompany.MyProgram)`

`start /b` is there to avoid the cmd-window to stick around

Comment: Thanks. This works very well for my case. It removed the need of having a batch-file or knowing where and how Java is installed.

Answer (score 0):

> If I run a program that exists in %PATH% in Windows when there is a program with the same name in the current folder it will select the one in current folder instead. Is there any way to prevent this (to disregard current folder)?

No. This is the mechanism most operating systems work: Since you explicitely start the program from a certain folder, your program runs with that folder as working directory.

> The problem is that on one computer I tested on it didn't work. It complained about the wrong JRE version (1.7 instead of 1.8). I found that on this computer someone installed JRE 1.8 over 1.7, but the 1.7 files are still left in Windows\System32.

Then your solution definitely shouldn't be changing the working directory but explicitely enforcing a minimal Java version by explicitely calling the right one with the correct paths set.

Just use a cmd batch file that correctly calls Java.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Actually, not all OS works like Windows in this case. In UNIX it will only search the path, the only way to launch from current folder is to write ./ before the command name. So leaving out ./ would achieved what I wanted in UNIX (that way you are not dependant on the working directory when you launch a script).

Comment: @user1123407: what you write about unixoids is wrong. The working directory of a program by default is the working directory of the process that `fork`ed or `exec`ed the process. 
You're confusing working directory and search paths. the first is a OS concept, whereas search paths are just a shell convention on where to look to find programs. Under most unixoids, it's not customary for this list of paths to contain the current directory, but it's perfectly possible to `export PATH=.:$PATH` which emulates Window's default behaviour of looking into the current working directory first.